# fetchAll getting stuck

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetchall

I have the following code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT table.field, table2.field2 FROM
                table, table2";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $x = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I know it is not enough information, but I do not understand why the code executes only if I comment the fetchAll line. When that line executes, I do not get anything, just blank browser, no errors or anything. In firebug the response is blank... What can it be??

Comment: What do you expect to see in browser? Check if error reporting turned on in php.ini. Also, are you handling MySQL errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing a **Cartesian product** of `table` and `table2`. This can be a HUGE amount of data.

For each row in table, you are getting all the rows in `table2`. So if `table` has 100 lines, and table2 has 500 lines, **your query will try to fetch 50.000 lines.**

You'll either want a JOIN:

```
SELECT table.field, table2.field2 
FROM table 
JOIN table2 
ON table.field3 = table2.field3
```

Or a UNION

```
SELECT table.field AS FIELDNAME FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.field2 AS FIELDNAME FROM table2
```

If a Cartesian product is really what you want, try adding a LIMIT and see if that works. Then later increase or remove the limit

```
SELECT table.field, table2.field2 
FROM table, table2 LIMIT 10
```

Depending on what your tables contain (you indeed did not give enough info).

Comment: it is a lot of data :p why would that be a problem?

Comment: @luqita: because PHP has fairly hefty memory overhead for storing even the smallest/simplest of data. You're basically trying to load the entire contents of your two tables, SQUARED, into memory.

Comment: Try getting smaller data first. If that works, you are hitting certain imposed limits. Maybe your PHP script has a maximum execution time set, or you're running out of memory, or your request timed out...

Comment: PHP tends to have a limit on memory and time useage (per default, it is somewhat in the thirty seconds area), which you can change in the php.ini. That is almost every single time a bad idea. You should try to improve your code before even thinking about that.

Comment: Try executing the SQL query in another (My)SQL client (commandline mysql, phpmyadmin, MySQL Workbench, Toad, ...) and see the results...

Comment: I changed it to using joins but the same thing is happening. By the way, why does this only happen when using fetchAll? If I don't use fetchAll the code just goes through, which maybe means the SQL is not bad?

Comment: It's legal SQL, it just generates a very large result set.  MySQL can do that all right, but PHP can't fetch and hold a result that large.

Comment: @luqita: that is interesting. Can update your question and post the code that does work? Also, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE2` would be nice, as well as the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` of your select :)

Answer (score 0):

For catching errors you should enabled error_reporting and display_errors.
I think the cause of this behavior is that you get 'allowed memory limit'. Maybe you get too many rows from db.

Try to add ini_set('memory_limit', '256M') and check working.